# Name conflicts and closure in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code :

```
function outside() {
   var x = 10;
   function inside(x) {
      return x;
   }
   return inside;
}
 result = outside()(20); // returns 20 instead of 10
```

Why the function return 20 instead of 10
and why i cant not call the outdise function with outside (20) instead of outside ()(2) ;
why ()?

Comment: You wrote a function that returns the value passed in to it.

Comment: Because JavaScript resolves the more local variable first.

Comment: For the second part of your question, `outside()` will return a function object, but will not call that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very "homeworky" question, but ...

The following is exactly the same as what you wrote:

```
var inside = function (x) { return x }
var outside = function () {
  var x = 10;
  return inside;
}
```

Stepping through the function call: `var result = outside()(20)`, we see that this is the exact same as

```
var result = outside();  // result == inside
result(20);              // same as calling inside(20), which returns 20.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you refer to a variable name, JavaScript will attempt to resolve the reference starting from the most local scope.  In this instance:

```
function outside() {
   var x = 10; // This is the second most local
   function inside(x) { // The x variable here is the most local
      return x; // x will be the most local variable named x, ie the parameter
   }
   return inside;
}
```

You'll get whatever you passed in to the `inside()` function.  Now, if you had *this*:

```
function outside() {
   var x = 10; // This is now the most local
   function inside(y) { // Renamed the parameter to y
      return x; // returns the variable x
   }
   return inside;
}
```

Then you'd get 10, as the `y` parameter no longer interferes with the `x` variable within the `outside()` function.  The value of `x` will be maintained even after the `outside()` function exits through a mechanism known as *closures*.

Now imagine you had:

```
var x = 5; // This is a global variable
function outside() {
   var x = 10; // This is the most local
   function inside(y) {
      return x; // x here will refer to the x with a value of 10
   }
   return inside;
}
```

In this case, you would also get 10, as the `x` variable inside the `outside()` function is *more local* than the global `x` variable.

As for your function call:

```
result = outside()(20);
```

The expression `outside()` is calling the function `outside`, which returns a reference to the function `inside()`:

```
return inside; // Inside is a function, we're not calling it because there are no parens
```

You're then *calling* that function you have a reference to (ie, the `inside` function) and passing in the parameter value of 20.  If the double paranthesis are confusing, you can think of it like this:

```
var foo = outside(); // foo is a reference to a function
result = foo(20); // We're now calling that function, passing in 20 as the parameter
```

Your `inside()` function returns that value of `20`, which is set to the variable `result`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the function return 20 instead of 10

When there is a naming conflict the inner scope takes precedence.

> why i cant not call the outdise function with outside (20) instead of outside ()(2) ; why ()?

Calling `outside()` returns a function (as you can see from `return inner`).  You then invoke that function.  If you were to call `outside(20)` it would still return the inner function.  If you expand this, it may be more clear:

```
var outResult = outside();  // outside returns `inner`, the variable now contains that function

outResult(20);  // call the inner function passing the value 20
```

Comment: so if i understand correct :
outside () is the same as outside (2) ?

and the returned function (inside), i call then with (x=20 ) and not the "x" that is in the outResult ? (that is 10)

Comment: `outside()` has the same result as `outside(2)` only because `outside` does not do anything with the argument passed to it.